# Polars aggregate without a groupby

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

Is there a way to call `.agg()` without grouping first? I want to perform standard aggregations but only want one row in the response, rather than separate rows for separate groups.

I could do something like

```
df.with_columns(dummy_col=pl.lit("dummy_col")).group_by('dummy_col').agg(<aggregateion>)
```

but I'm wondering if there's a way without the dummy stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When all expressions within a `select` context are aggregations, the resulting dataframe only has a single row.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "b": [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
})
```

```py
df.select(pl.col("a").mean(), pl.col("b").first())
```

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 3.0 ┆ 0   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score -3):

Ofcourse, you can use a dictionary to match desired operation for any column like this:

```
data = {
    "A": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "B": [5, 6, 7, 8],
    "C": [9, 10, 11, 11]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

aggregations = {
    "A": "sum",
    "B": "mean",
    "C": "max"
}
result = df.agg(aggregations)

print(result)
```

output:

[image]

Or simply this one liner would also work:

```
df.agg({"A": "sum","B": "mean","C": "max"})
```

**With polars library:**

```
df.select(pl.col("A").sum(),pl.col("B").mean(),pl.col("C").max())
```